# Why does yacc or bison translate $1 to yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s?

Tags: c, bison, yacc

Yacc source as below:

```
element:    IDENTIFIER                { $$ = gst_element_factory_make ($1, NULL);
                        if ($$ == NULL) {
                          ADD_MISSING_ELEMENT (graph, $1);
                          SET_ERROR (graph->error, GST_PARSE_ERROR_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT, _("no element \"%s\""), $1);
                          /* if FATAL_ERRORS flag is set, we don't have to worry about backwards
                           * compatibility and can continue parsing and check for other missing
                           * elements */
                          if ((graph->flags & GST_PARSE_FLAG_FATAL_ERRORS) == 0) {
                            gst_parse_strfree ($1);
                            YYERROR;
                          }
                        }
                        gst_parse_strfree ($1);
                                              }
    |   element ASSIGNMENT        { gst_parse_element_set ($2, $1, graph);
                        $$ = $1;
```

It is translated to code like this:

```
 { (yyval.e) = gst_element_factory_make ((yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s), NULL);
                    if ((yyval.e) == NULL) {
                      ADD_MISSING_ELEMENT (graph, (yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s));
                      SET_ERROR (graph->error, GST_PARSE_ERROR_NO_SUCH_ELEMENT, _("no element \"%s\""), (yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s));
                      /* if FATAL_ERRORS flag is set, we don't have to worry about backwards
                       * compatibility and can continue parsing and check for other missing
                       * elements */
                      if ((graph->flags & GST_PARSE_FLAG_FATAL_ERRORS) == 0) {
                        gst_parse_strfree ((yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s));
                        YYERROR;
                      }
                    }
                    gst_parse_strfree ((yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s));
                                          }
break;
```

One of the translations converts:

```
gst_element_factory_make ($1, NULL)
```

to:

```
gst_element_factory_make ((yyvsp[(1) - (1)].s), NULL)
```

The `[(1) - (1)]` is confusing me.
Why is `[(1) - (1)]` sentence representative of `$1` value?

Comment: `yyvsp` is a pointer to (part of) an array that holds (pointers to) the values corresponding to `$1`, `$2`, etc.  The value of `$1` is stored at `yyvsp[0]`, which can be written as `yyvsp[(1) - (1)]` where the first `1` is the suffix to the `$1` and the second is a literal 1.  It's machine generated code and you are not expected to read it.  If you do, you have to accept it is (1) correct and (2) convenient for a program to produce rather than for a programmer to read.

Comment: And the `.s` part is because you have a union type, and the type of `$1` (`IDENTIFIER`) is such that the value is stored in the `s` element of the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonathan Leffler says in a comment, bison and yacc generate correct code in a style convenient for code generation, not for human readers.

However, the handling of the various stacks is fairly straight-forward. Bison maintains two or three stacks: the state stack; the value stack; and optionally the location stack. The three stacks are independent because otherwise it would be necessary to create a stack slot structure containing the state, value and (if necessary) location.

The stacks are always the same size, which means that there is an unused slot at the beginning of the values stack (and also the location stack). If you refer to the classic description of the LR parsing algorithm, say in the "LR Parsing Algorithm" section of the Dragon Book -- §4.7 in the edition I have -- you will see this clearly; the stack has one more state than grammar symbol, so there is no `X0`:

```
s0 X1 s1 X2 s2 … Xm sm
```

(Bison doesn't actually keep the grammar symbol on the stack, since the symbol itself can easily be computed. Instead, it keeps the semantic value associated with the symbol.)

In the code, `yyvsp` and `yyssp` are pointers to the top of the value and state stacks, respectively. (`yylsp` is a pointer to the top of the location stack, if there is one.)

They actually point to the top element of their respective stack, rather than pointing one past the top element. The one-past-the-top-element pointer is more common in general stack implementations because in general there may not be a top element to point at, if the stack is empty. However, in this particular case the stacks are never empty, so there is always a top element. (At the beginning of the algorithm, the top state is `0` and the top value and location are the unused slots mentioned above.) As always, the rest of the stack goes down from the top, so the second-last element (if there is one) is at `yyvsp - 1`, and the third-last element at `yyvsp - 2`.

Remember that in C, `*yyvsp` means exactly the same thing as `yyvsp[0]`. Or, in general, `yyvsp[k]` is the same as `*(yyvsp + k)`. That's true even if `k` is negative, so we can write `yyvsp[-1]` to refer to the second-last element in the stack.

The code you quote implements the reduction action of a production; the reduction action generally computes the semantic value of the resulting non-terminal. Suppose the production being reduced is:

```
A → X1 X2 … Xm
```

In that case, the top of the value stack will be precisely

```
V1 V2 … Vm
```

(where `Vi` is the semantic value of the symbol `Xi`). Or, in bison terms:

`$1 $2 … $m`

That means that `$1` is `yyvsp[1-m]`, `$2` is `yyvsp[2-m]`, and so on, up to `$m` at `yyvsp[m-m]`. And that's precisely what the code generated by bison does; it represents `$i` as `yyvsp[(i)-(m)]` where `m` is the length (in grammar symbols) of the right-hand side being reduced.